# Correct processor to start assembly language

Tags: assembly

What will be the correct micro processor /controller to get a in depth knowledge of processor and assembly language? i have tried learning 8086 without completely knowing about assembly language and  that each family of microprocessors have their own assembly language . Can somebody suggest the most basic processor to start with

Comment: Sounds pointless. You would better study assembly based on the processor which you intend to work with, rather than for just some arbitrary processor.

Comment: I want to  know how a computer works .I don't have any specific processor to work on right now

Comment: Can You please suggest me. A processor to know the basics.

Comment: There's no such thing as "how a computer works". Different computers work in different ways.

Comment: Then also suggest a processor which would be correct for a begginer

Comment: Generally, the older a processor design is, the simpler it is, so if you're going for simplicity, by all means study e.g. the [Intel 4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004), but once you need to start coding you'll need to know about the CPU that you physically have at your disposal.

Comment: Can't I use other cpu for learning other cpu?

Comment: Casually asking how did You started learning assembly language?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: There are some simplified toy ISAs like LC-3, and MIPS or RISC-V are common real-world choices for simpler ISAs without a lot of "weird stuff" that gains real-world efficiency.  (e.g. simple immediate encoding, unlike AArch64).  Mainstream C compilers can target MIPS and RISC-V, which is a huge advantage since then a machine can make examples for you.

Comment: Me? Mostly by looking at the CPU/disassembly window of the debugger for bits of code that I'd written in higher level languages, and then by reading books about it when seeing something I didn't understand (this was before the internet).

Comment: I started out learning asm on an Atari ST, for its m68k CPU.  That was what I / we (my dad) had at the time, and GCC ran so slow on it that I started playing around with the asm directly while optimizing a fixed-point Mandelbrot fractal program.  m68k is a nice clean ISA to learn, without any 8086 segmentation weirdness, but OTOH modern x86 uses a flat memory model so segmentation isn't an issue there, either.

Comment: : O I started C just 2-3 months  ago

Comment: I guess pretty much basics of C are clear to me and I can create some programs

Comment: So should I go with Assembly or should I learn something else before going to assembly

Comment: Anyway, questions like this asking for recommendations on how to start learning something are clearly off-topic for SO ( [ask] / [help]). So it should be closed, although it's fine to keep commenting I guess.   And it's not the first time someone has asked this, so I closed it as a duplicate of some existing Q&As.

Comment: This confusion is eating me and my college  is going slow af I want to advance but I don't  know which way to advance in.

Comment: Learning actual 8086 (with 16-bit real mode segmentation) is definitely *not* what I'd recommend learning first.  It's fairly easy to understand segmentation once you already understand how CPUs work and how assembly language works, and understand the problem it was designed to solve.  But learning it at the same time as asm basics just makes that harder.

Comment: Please guide me Till now I haven't understand which one to start on?

Comment: So what should I do first?????

Comment: Should I learn cpu architecture first ??